# International travel of minor with dual Japanese and US citizenship

Tags: international-travel, us-citizens, dual-nationality, japanese-citizens

I am the legal guardian of my niece. She has Japanese and US citizenships. She flew here, to the US, on her US passport. It has since expired and there is not enough time to renew it.

Can she fly back to Japan on her Japanese passport? It is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

The US does not have exit control so she does not need to show her US passport on the way out. 
For the airline it does (mostly) only matter that she has the right passport (and if needed visa) for her destination.

If asked why she does not have a visa for the US, she (or you if you are there) can show her expired US passport.

Before she comes to the US the next time she will have to get a new US passport.

Comment: Also, she should always go to Japan with her Japanese passport, or she will lose her Japanese citizenship if Japanese Immigration ever sees her US passport.

Comment: @dda: "she will lose her Japanese citizenship if Japanese Immigration ever sees her US passport" I'm not so sure about that. Japanese dual nationals do not have to make a choice of nationality until age 22, and even if they fail to make a choice by then, their Japanese nationality is still not automatically lost, unless and until the Japanese government asks them to make the choice and they fail to make the choice within 1 month.